# Как реализовать программу для автоматического удаления спама с почты

Tags: python, email, mail.ru

Заметил последнее время приходит много спама на почту (mail.ru), в связи с этим хочу написать прогу которая будет удалять все рассылки (либо по названию сообщения/удаление старых писем) на которые я не подписан.
Прогу буду писать на python 3.
Насколько мне стало понятно для написания этой программы нужно использовать imaplib - IMAP4.
Прошу Вас подсказать, дать совет как это сделать, ту ли я библиотеку хочу использовать или нужна другая, а возможно и в целом другой подход.
P.S. Смотрел документацию по imaplib - IMAP4 но мало что смог понять (https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html), быть может Вы подскажите где лучше смотреть.

Comment: Спам, это те сообщения которые находятся в папке спама, или которые вам просто не нравятся?

Comment: те сообщения которые мне не нравятся

Comment: нравятся не нравятся- это слишком расплывчато. вы планируете обучать нейросеть разделять спам не спам ?

Comment: нет, я буду в своей программе указывать либо email адреса с которых приходит нежелательная почта и программа будет удалять эти письма, либо я буду в программу вводить название письма и программа будет удалять все писам с таким названием.        P.S. Нейросети и т.п. я использовать не буду.

Comment: Для описанного вами функционала imaplib более чем достаточно. Вот хороший [пример](https://coderoad.ru/3180891/imap-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)  удаления сообщений. Удачи!

Comment: Простите, а зачем для этого python? В настройках того же mail.ru вы можете настроить автоматические фильтры для сноса писем от неугодных получателей

Comment: И в дополнение комментария @andreymal скажу, что от рассылок можно просто отписаться, нажав соответствующую кнопку в письме рассылки. Это даже будет несколько полезней настройки фильтра, и гораздо проще того, что вы затеяли